# How can I satisfy the At-Most constraint in a workflow satisfiability problem with Google OR-Tools?

Tags: python, constraints, workflow, or-tools, sat

For a given set of steps T, I have to ensure that at most k users are assigned to steps T. For example, at most 2 users can be assigned to steps 1, 2, and 3.  Each task is only assigned to one user and a user can have multiple tasks.
I have already made boolvar assignments for every pair of users and steps, such that assignments[user_x, step_y] is true if user_x is assigned to step_y. I get data from an input file in the form of a list of lists, e.g. [[2,1,2,3], [3,1,2,3,4,5]] means 2 At-Most constraints, the first list meaning 2 maximum users for the group of steps 1, 2, and 3, and the second list meaning 3 maximum users for the group of steps 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

```
for list in range(len(at_most_k)):
    # get max number of users
    k = at_most_k[list][0]
    # get the group of steps
    group_of_steps = at_most_k[list][1:]
    user_group = []
    for steps in group_of_steps:
        for users in range(num_users):
            user_group.append(assignments[users, steps-1])
    model.Add(sum(user_group) <= k)
```

Actually, I've taken a look at the documentation provided by google OR-Tools at https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/assignment_teams
and modified it accordingly. I can confirm that editing the code provided by the above website to work on lists of lists, as I'm using, does work. However, the above code, which is supposed to be satisfiable, doesn't work.

Any explanation or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should clarify that there are other constraints besides this one and with those ones, the program returns sat, only after adding this constraint does it return unsat.

Comment: The code seems ok, are you sure it is satisfiable? can you check with a smaller example?

Comment: Agreed to unit testing your model. You can also inject a feasible solution to verify your model.